# How to change Stats.js size?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, size

I'm trying to change the size of the Stats.js canvas. I tried using CSS but I can't assign an id on that particular `canvas` element, so tried this:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal_container" id="modal_graph">        
   <img id="moveModalImage" src="images/moveIcon.png" alt="Move modal window."/>
   <span onclick='document.getElementById( "modal_graph" ).style.display= "none";' class="close-button">×</span>
   <p>Performance over Time Graph</p>
   <hr>

   <div id="modal_4-content">
     <!-- Add Stats.GUI here -->

   </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#modal_4-content canvas{
    width: 240px; //Doesn't work
    height: 150px; //Doesn't work
    float: left; //Works fine
    padding-right: 60px; //Works fine
}
```

JS:

```
function createStatsGUI(){

    var thisParent = document.getElementById("modal_4-content");

    //Create new Graph (FPS, MS, MB)
    stats1 = new Stats();

    //Display different panel
    stats1.showPanel( 0 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
    stats1.domElement.style.width = '200px';
    stats1.domElement.style.height = '200px';

    //Add Stats to Document - modal 4
    thisParent.appendChild( stats1.domElement );  
}
```

If you know how to change this please let me know. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 thisParent.firstChild.width =100;
 thisParent.firstChild.height=100;
```

Instead of

```
thisParent.child.style.height=100
```

Expected html in my case

```
 <div id="modal_4-content"><canvas></canvas>
 </div>
```

No space between parent and child

```
  <div id="modal_4-content"><canvas></canvas> 
           //canvas is the first element  here try Ur update 1,2,3
          //If not go with queryselector
   </div>
```

Queryselector

```
  var canvas = thisParent.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = 500;
  canvas.height = 500;
```

To draw canvas style is different will not affect wen resize canvas.You need  direct inline attribute to  change width and height on resize.

Comment: I updated my question. Your suggestion doesn't give an error. Although its not updating anything. Do you mean I have to access 2dContext of the canvas?

Comment: Add the canvas container pls html

Comment: Need to know how canvas generated inside tat contaier        <div id="modal_4-content">
     <!-- Add Stats.GUI here -->
            <canvas></canvas>  ?????
           //canvas is the first element  here try Ur 
   </div>

Comment: I use this `thisParent.appendChild( stats1.domElement );` so the <canvas> element goes just right in the middle of `<div id="modal_4-content">`.

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem:

```
function createStatsGUI(){

    //Create new Graphs (FPS, MS, MB)
    statsGUI = new Stats();
    statsGUI.showPanel( 0 ); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom

    var thisParent = document.getElementById("modal_4-content");
    thisParent.appendChild( statsGUI.domElement );

    var statsALL = document.getElementById("modal_4-content").querySelectorAll("canvas");

    for(var i=0; i<statsALL.length; i++){
        statsALL[i].style.width = "100%";
        statsALL[i].style.height = "160px";
        //...
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's why i asked  Html content

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get all child nodes by using [.childnodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)

Comment: I've tried using this `var childs = thisParent.childnodes; childs[0]....; child[1]...;` it only works on the first child. However its not changing the size